# Multiple conditions in .htaccess redirect 301 and 404

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have multiple domains in a single IP (a single root)

Any 404 on domain1.com or domain1.com.ve (http or https) (www. or not) must redirect to https://www.domain1.com/home/index.php

Any 404 on domain2.com or domain2.com.ve (http or https) (www. or not) must redirect to https://www.domain2.com/index.php

Any 404 on domain3.com or domain3.com.ve (http or https) (www. or not) must redirect to https://www.domain3.com/index.php

domain2 an domain3 goes to the same index.php, but keeping the original domain name.

At the same time any legal request in http must redirect to https

Is that possible to do?